# problem with Web page refreshing in production

Tags: node.js, vue.js, .htaccess, page-refresh

I have just deployed my site on planet hoster.
The front is coded with vueJs, the back nodeJs.
In production, refreshing the visited page does not work, and I get the error:
"The requested URL was not found on this server."
In development the page reloads, I don't have the problem.

I tried to add a piece of code to the .htaccess with this:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule . /index.html [L]`
`</ifModule>
`
```

it works but it has the effect of preventing all my API requests!

Here is what is in my .htacces located in the root of my API directory:

```
"# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/xxxx/api"
PassengerBaseURI "/api"
PassengerNodejs "/home/xxxx/xxxx/api/16/bin/node"
PassengerAppType node
PassengerStartupFile server.js
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END"
```

An idea ?

Thanks,

Fred